# Low volume Open source Message Board suggestions?

Tags: php, python, html, ruby

Looking for a low volume, probably no more that 20-30 users, Open Source message/bulletin board.  Obviously must be written in something which our web server supports, PHP/Python/Ruby etc.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
  Nick

Answer (score 2):

- [FUDForum](http://fudforum.org/forum/)
- [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/)

and lots more. The above are designed to handle very large boards, but can be used with low traffic websites. All PHP

Answer (score 0):

PhpBB http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpBB free and open Source, requires MySQL. Great for running on run-of-the-mill LAMP configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Vanilla forums](http://vanillaforums.org/) in your case. It has a great API for integrating into other projects as well.

Or if you prefer the more traditional forum layout see [PunBB](http://punbb.informer.com/).

I would **not** recommend phpBB for a low volume forum as it is more complicated to setup and maintain. It is also a much larger app and not lightweight at all.

Answer (score 0):

PhpBB is an excellent. It's very easy to set up and has many great features, but it is more difficult to customize right out of the box. For a superfast "community" solution, try using WordPress with the BuddyPress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend MyLittleForum. It's actually not a board, but a forum, but one of the views (with compacted threads) looks pretty much board-like. http://mylittleforum.net/forum/index.php?mode=index